# MySQL Join twice on the same table gives half of the result

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

I have 2 tables and making join query, thing is that in the main table I have 2 columns with id which needs to be replaced with full names from second table, thats why I am running query over same table twice. Thing is that it hasn't roughly half of the records, if I change position of joins then second half appears. data in identifier 2 columns are something like that: (271, 272), (272, 271)

```
    query = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT * from transactions {2} LIMIT {3}, {4}) as transactions " \
            "LEFT JOIN (SELECT account_number as dr, account_name as dr_n, acc_id, company_id, deleted FROM tb_accounts) as tb1 ON tb1.acc_id = transactions.dr_acc " \
            "LEFT JOIN (SELECT account_number as cr, account_name as cr_n, acc_id, company_id, deleted FROM tb_accounts) as tb2 ON tb2.acc_id = transactions.cr_acc " \
            "LEFT JOIN (SELECT document as doc_name, doc_id, company_id, deleted FROM documents ORDER BY documents.date DESC) as doc1 ON doc1.doc_id = transactions.document " \
            "and doc1.company_id = {0} and doc1.deleted = 0 " \
            "WHERE tb1.company_id = {0} and tb1.deleted = 0 and " \
            "tb2.company_id = {0} and tb2.deleted = 0 and " \
            "transactions.company_id = {0} and {1} transactions.deleted = 0".format(company_id, filter, sort, sn, en)
```

Comment: It is not 100% clear what your parameters mean. If you could provide their example values, I may adjust my answer a bit. Also could you please provide an example data and what differences you have changing positions of the joins. Please edit your question instead of posting additional information into comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query looks quite convoluted and could be executed quite slowly by generating the temporary tables to use in joins.

Also I don't believe you need `LEFT JOIN` there. Instead it should be `JOIN` (`INNER JOIN`).

And a cause of your problem is the LIMIT operator posted on top.

I could suggest using the following query (have a look how I put it in Python - it is much more convenient to copy/paste and test in a DB client):

```
query = """
    SELECT *
    FROM transactions as transactions
    JOIN tb_accounts as tb1
    ON tb1.acc_id = transactions.dr_acc AND tb1.deleted = 0 AND tb1.company_id = {0}
    JOIN tb_accounts as tb2
    ON tb2.acc_id = transactions.cr_acc AND tb2.deleted = 0 AND tb2.company_id = {0}
    JOIN documents as doc1
    ON doc1.doc_id = transactions.document
        AND doc1.company_id = {0}
        AND doc1.deleted = 0
    WHERE transactions.company_id = {0}
      AND transactions.deleted = 0
      {1}
    {2}
    LIMIT {3}, {4}
""".format(company_id, filter, sort, sn, en)
```

---

To optimize speed of the query above, the following indexes would be useful:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_del_comp_acc
ON tb_accounts (deleted, company_id, acc_id);

CREATE INDEX idx_del_comp_doc
ON documents (deleted, company_id, doc_id);

CREATE INDEX idx_del_comp_dr_acc
ON transactions (deleted, company_id, dr_acc);

CREATE INDEX idx_del_comp_cr_acc
ON transactions (deleted, company_id, cr_acc);
```

It is important to have columns in your indexes in a sequence as above.

Also It is important what other conditions you have when running the query, and also what other queries you would run. In that case you could add more indexes or redesign those above.

Use a command `EXPLAIN` in front of your query to see how the server is going to run it and what indexes will be used if any.

Keep in mind though, that adding an index increases time of the INSERT and UPDATE requests. Usually benefits of having an index outweigh times over having a bit slower inserts.

Comment: Just tested and it worked. thank you. only issue now I have is that I have 1 million database in transactions and it takes 2 min to list 1000 records.

Comment: @SandroShubladze, I have added indexes to my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I will use that.

Comment: I tried and It was perfect and gave gorgeous performance. Thank you very much